# Is there any issue with creating singleton following way in .Net ?

Tags: c#

I want to create a Singleton for my class, I have the following code, it works fine but is there any potential issue which I am not able to see ?

```
public class Singleton
    {
        private static Singleton _singleton;
        private Singleton()
        {

        }
        public static Singleton GetInstance()
        {
            Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _singleton, new Singleton(), null);
            return _singleton;
        }
        public void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($" Hello from {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may want to direct this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: If you're fine with creating multiple instances of `Singleton`, as long as only one wins, then the code should work fine. But yes, check the duplicate.